# Python Creating a new list from a nested list containing Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, nested-lists

Given is the Input List, which contains the dictionaries.

```
Input=[
       {"rbd":"x","cat":"xxx","origin":"us"},
       {"rbd":"y","cat":"xxx","origin":"us"},
       {"rbd":"z","cat":"xxx","origin":"us"},
       {"rbd":"q","cat":"xxx","origin":"us"},
       {"rbd":"1","cat":"xxy","origin":"us"},
       {"rbd":"2","cat":"xxy","origin":"us"}
                                              ]
```

I am trying to get this as an output.
here, if key "cat" and key "origin" are same for dictionaries inside the Input list then it adds them to the one "rbd". else it creates a new. Below is the output.

```
Output=[{"rbd":["x","y","z","q"],"cat":"xxx","origin":"us"},
        {"rbd":["l","2"],"cat":"xxy","origin":"us"}]
```

I tried the following incomplete implementation. To first convert the List into a dictionary. It throws an error.

```
def Convert(lst): 
    Input_Dict = {lst[i]: lst[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)} 
    return Input_Dict
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: @KuldeepSinghSidhu Its unclear what you said, I tried few incomplete implementations but that did not work. Hence I came here. Your comment is confusing. There are many such examples for such use cases, where people ask questions in this same manner. If you require I can show you what implementation I have done. Please specify how you came to this conclusion that I want a CODE- WRITING service??

Comment: @RishabhGaur His comment showed no offense.There always some people ask his question without attempt.So when you posted your question, you didn't show some effort(Although you have tried, you didn't add it in your post in the past).You could see some [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288176/is-showing-effort-needed) on meta.Right, now you add it in your post.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Right. But it's better to refrain being judgmental. Thanks for understanding, I edited the post to show my implementations. I can update if I make progress until them if someone has few insights and is willing to share I am all glad. But this manner is discouraging if not Offensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

Input = [{"rbd": "x", "cat": "xxx", "origin": "us"},
         {"rbd": "y", "cat": "xxx", "origin": "us"},
         {"rbd": "z", "cat": "xxx", "origin": "us"},
         {"rbd": "q", "cat": "xxx", "origin": "us"},
         {"rbd": "1", "cat": "xxy", "origin": "us"},
         {"rbd": "2", "cat": "xxy", "origin": "us"}]

print([{"rbd": [i["rbd"] for i in item], "cat": k[0], "origin": k[1]} for k, item in groupby(Input, key=lambda x: (x["cat"], x["origin"]))])
```

This gives me:

```
[{'rbd': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'q'], 'cat': 'xxx', 'origin': 'us'}, {'rbd': ['1', '2'], 'cat': 'xxy', 'origin': 'us'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should loop over Input, and for each element check if cat and origin exist in Output. If it is already there, put the `rbd` of Input in the Output. If it doesn't exist, create a new map in Output.

*Note that this is not the most effective answer.*

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this challenge is via [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the [collections](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#module-collections) module :

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for entry in Input:
    d[(entry["cat"], entry["origin"])].append(entry["rbd"])

print(d)
defaultdict(list,
        {('xxx', 'us'): ['x', 'y', 'z', 'q'], ('xxy', 'us'): ['1', '2']})


keys = ("rbd", "cat", "origin")

#list comprehension to get final output
[dict(zip(keys, (value, *key))) for key, value in d.items()]

[{'rbd': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'q'], 'cat': 'xxx', 'origin': 'us'},
 {'rbd': ['1', '2'], 'cat': 'xxy', 'origin': 'us'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

One can perform Itertools.groupby as mentioned in one of the answers here.
Another way is to convert the list of dicts to a dataframe and then perform groupby and then convert back to list of dicts.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(Input)
df1 = df.groupby(by=['origin', 'cat'])['rbd'].apply(list).reset_index()
df_dicts = df1.to_dict("records")
print(df_dicts)
```